# Google Directions API Greek Characters JSON result iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, google-maps

I make a request to a url to get directions for some POIs from Google Direction API.

Although when the string that has been parsed contains Greek Characters i get some strange chracters as result from JSON.

Here is an example of my problem.

"Take the 1st **left** toward **\U0399\U03c0\U03c0\U03bf\U03ba\U03c1\U03ac\U03c4\U03bf\U03c5\U03c2**"

Here is the code that gets these strings.The values that i want to use are into ins array.

```
NSDictionary *routes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"][0];

NSDictionary *legs=[routes objectForKey:@"legs"][0];

NSArray *steps=[legs objectForKey:@"steps"];


NSMutableArray *ins=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<steps.count; i++) {

    [ins addObject:[[steps objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"html_instructions"]];

}
```

Here is the url that i want to parse correctly:

[Json url](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=39.537597,20.200750&destination=39.439885,20.353189&sensor=false&waypoints=optimize:true%7C39.534600,20.353189)

What i have to do?